# SVG animation in Angular 14

Tags: angular, animation, svg

I have animation in my component

```
animations: [
  trigger('start', [
    transition(':enter', [
      style({ 'stroke-dashoffset': '620' }),
      animate(15000, style({ 'stroke-dashoffset': '0' })),
    ]),
  ]),
],
```

thats worked fine before Angular was updated to version 14.

Now I get warning, and animation doesn't work

```
Warning: The animation trigger "start" is attempting to animate the following not animatable properties: stroke-dashoffset
(to check the list of all animatable properties visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_animated_properties)
```

There is no SVG properties that can be animated. So, how I can realise animation?

Comment: I am running into the same issue, have ou figured something out?

Comment: I moved the animation to a separate component and use built-in svg animate tag for it. So the animation starts along with the initialization of the component